# FCC Low Oscilation

Tags: avr, fcc

I have heard that if a circuit is operating at less then 1.2 MHz it does not need FCC certification.

Does an ATMega328 with with a 1Mhz External crystal, and the internal clock not used qualify for this exemption.  Or does does the AVR use the internal 8Mhz clock for other stuff that I am not aware and thus not satisfactory for this exemption?

Taken from https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title47-vol1/pdf/CFR-2011-title47-vol1-sec15-103.pdf

> "(h)  Digital  devices  in  which  both  the highest  frequency  generated  and  the highest  frequency  used  are  less  than
>   1.705  MHz  and  which  do  not  operate from  the  AC  power  lines  or  contain provisions   for   operation   while   connected  to  the  AC  power  lines.  Digital devices that include, or make provision for  the  use  of,  battery  eliminators,  AC adaptors   or   battery   chargers   which permit   operation   while   charging   or that  connect  to  the  AC  power  lines  indirectly, obtaining their power through another  device  which  is  connected  to the  AC  power  lines,  do  not  fall  under
>   this exemption. "

Comment: A 1MHz crystal oscillator will produce harmonics well above 1 MHz so I doubt that running a CPU at 1MHz is an adequate way to sidestep FCC requirements.

Comment: @BrianDrummond How can I calculate the harmonics generated?

Comment: Frequencies? Trivial. Amplitudes? you may be able to simulate them but practically you would have to measure them - essentially the FCC certification process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the external crystal source is selected, the internal oscillator is disabled. So if you use a 1MHz external crystal, then yes, nothing in the AVR will be operating above 1MHz.

The AVR in its default configuration uses the 8MHz oscillator but internally divided by 8. So nothing outside the IC or even inside the chip after the prescaler will be running above 1.2MHz, so theoretically (though I'm not a lawyer, so don't take my word for this) that may not require certification either.

---

Note: The above is answering the question of whether the internal clock is enabled or not. I have in no way attempted to verify whether the 1.2MHz limit you mention in the question is correct or not. See @jp314's answer.

Comment: No I don't think that would count....but definitely going to get a ton of 1Mhz crystals now

Answer (score 4):

No - the FCC restricts devices operating above 9 kHz: http://transition.fcc.gov/Bureaus/Engineering_Technology/Documents/bulletins/oet62/oet62rev.pdf

Comment: Page 8 has a third number, 1.705 MHz.

Comment: Sub 9kHz any device is exempt.  Sub 1.705MHz any device *operating on battery power only* is exempt.